# Build Rust static library to use within CGO

Tags: go, rust, cgo, solana

I am trying to build my Rust crate as static lib to furter use it within Golang through FFI.
So far tried buch of different approaches regarding linking, but still having `undefined reference` kind error from final go binary:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libsolana_mint.a(nix-6da6fd938c826d01.nix.e161731d-cgu.5.rcgu.o): in function `nix::mqueue::mq_open':
nix.e161731d-cgu.5:(.text._ZN3nix6mqueue7mq_open17hd889faf637ea61f3E+0xd): undefined reference to `mq_open'
/usr/bin/ld: nix.e161731d-cgu.5:(.text._ZN3nix6mqueue7mq_open17hd889faf637ea61f3E+0x1e): undefined reference to `mq_open'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libsolana_mint.a(nix-6da6fd938c826d01.nix.e161731d-cgu.5.rcgu.o): in function `nix::mqueue::mq_unlink':
nix.e161731d-cgu.5:(.text._ZN3nix6mqueue9mq_unlink17hc51e2d94961b863cE+0x6): undefined reference to `mq_unlink'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libsolana_mint.a(nix-6da6fd938c826d01.nix.e161731d-cgu.5.rcgu.o): in function `nix::mqueue::mq_close':
nix.e161731d-cgu.5:(.text._ZN3nix6mqueue8mq_close17h53f48d4def20adadE+0x3): undefined reference to `mq_close'
```

All errors refer bunch of Rust crates from dependencies, such as `nix`, `solana_sdk`

Here is my Dockerfile, from Which I build it:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM rust:1.58 as build

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libudev-dev && apt-get install -y pkg-config

WORKDIR /solana
COPY lib/solana_mint ./solana_mint

WORKDIR /solana/solana_mint
RUN RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --release


FROM golang:1.17

WORKDIR /cardforge
COPY --from=build /solana/solana_mint/target/release/libsolana_mint.a ./lib/
COPY ./lib/solana_mint.h ./lib/

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY controllers ./controllers
COPY models ./models
COPY *.go ./

RUN go build main.go

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "RUST_LOG=trace ./main" ]
```

Will greatly appreciate any info, as for `cgo` there isn't much resources with advanced examples, exept plain hello-workd with single function binding

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem but start with a proper use of go build: Don't supply filename arguments to go build. (Actually do not provide filename arguments to most of the go subcommands ever).

Comment: Can you build this app outside of Docker? If so you need to trace back the missing library dependencies & ensure these pkgs are installed in your Docker build layer.

Comment: Are you using either `#[no_mangle]` or `#[link_name]` on the Rust functions you're trying to call from Go? Also, you need `extern "C"` to make sure the calling convention is correct.

Comment: @Solomon Ucko, yes using both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in right flags for CGO.
This is how header for CGO in main.go looks now

```
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: ./lib/libsolana_mint.a -ldl -ludev -lrt -lm
#include "./lib/solana_mint.h"
*/
import "C"
```

Adding `-ludev -rt -lm` solved all errors from linker and Docker image compiled.

Strange though, that this moment isn't lightened in any docs for FFI